# Rails Data Modelling: How to establish relationships when 2 Objects "Share" the same has_many list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, activerecord-relation

In a nutshell, when I create a `Transaction` Record it has two **foreign keys**. for the two users that participate in a `Transaction`, ie:

[image]

Now, What I would like to know with your kind help, is How do I establish the **relationship(s)** between: `User` and `Transaction` Models, so that I can easily retrieve ALL the `Transaction`s for either of the two `User`s.

Something like:

```
  user_one = User.find(1)
  user_two = User.find(2)

  user_one.transactions # returns all Transactions where user_one.id == 
                        # user_one_id Or user_one.id == user_two_id

  user_two.transactions # returns all Transactions where user_two.id == 
                        # user_one_id Or user_two.id == user_two_id
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Is it best to establish foreign keys in the Transaction Model in this case? Or is this a problem to be solved via `ActiveRecordQuery` only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two user ids and want to query `Transaction` on some combination of them, you can use an `or` clause:

```
>> Transaction.where(user_one_id: 1).or(Transaction.where(user_two_id: 2))
  Transaction Load (4.3ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE ("transactions"."user_one_id" = $1 OR "transactions"."user_two_id" = $2) LIMIT $3  [["user_one_id", 1], ["user_two_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Transaction id: 1, user_one_id: 1, user_two_id: 2, created_at: "2017-09-12 23:25:39", updated_at: "2017-09-12 23:25:39">]>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks @Tom Copeland. But shouldn't it be:
Transaction.where(user_one_id: 1).or(Transaction.where(user_two_id: 1)) ?

Comment: Oh, you are right - I misunderstood which set of ids the query was using.  But yup seems like `or` is the way to go here.

Comment: That would do it, right? I guess the additional Question comes down to, do I make user_one_id and user_two_id Foreign keys? is it necessary?

Comment: Yup usually I would make them foreign keys to preserve referential integrity, and of course you could make them nullable if needed.

Comment: Hey, If you don't mind, could you please post an example of how to make those columns foreign keys properly? Having a hard time finding an example myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: You bet - in your `create_table` migration you can do `t.references :user_one, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}` and `t.references :user_two, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}`.

Answer (score 1):

this is sample code

```
class Transaction
  def move
    return ""
  end
end

class User1 < Transaction
  def move
    return 'User1 move: X'
  end
end


class User2 < Transaction
  def move
    return'User2 move: O'
  end
end



transactions = [User1.new, User2.new]
transactions.each {|tran|
  print tran.move
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use polymorfic assossiations that can solve this issue I am in the train now will provide you with code or you can start looking up for this task and good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not sure how will a polymorphic association fit into this problem, May I kindly ask for some sample code? that's when you can provide it of course.